# Undo copy operation?

Tags: linux

I using virtualbox 5.1 and unexpectedly copied data from one file to another file ......

Below mentioned detail present in picture :

Actually I want to copy data from Unicell_test.vbox-prev to Unicell_test.vbox  but I copied data from Unicell_test.vbox-prev to Unicell_test.vhd .

So I can't start my virtual machine help me out how undo this operation.[image]

Comment: How did you copy the data? If you just did a `cp` then you've most likely overwritten the entire `vhd` with your `vbox-prev` file, which means the VM's hard drive has been deleted.